# Simplify list of tuples based on contiguous points

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples where the first item in each tuple is the start distance along a route and the second item is the ending distance along that route.

```
>>> MyTuples=[(0,100),(100,150),(150,180),(180,190),(400,450),(450,700)]
>>> MyTuples
[(0, 100), (100, 150), (150, 180), (180, 190), (400, 450), (450, 700)]
>>>
```

The first item in the list goes from point 0 to point 100, the second goes from point 100 to 150 and so on.

However, I want to simplify this list by aggregating on those items that are continuous. That would reduce the list to: `[(0,190),(400,700)]`

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

With a generator, you could do this with something like:

```py
def aggregate(tuples):
    current = None
    for (x, y) in tuples:
        if current == None:
            current = (x, y)
        else:
            (a, b) = current
            if b == x:  # should this be b >= x?
                current = (a, y)
            else:
                yield current
                current = (x, y)
    if current != None:
        yield current
```

In terms of functional programming this has a structural idiom which can be factored out called `foldl` which is common to all streams. You would write in Haskell,

```hs
aggregate (x:xs) = reverse $ foldl chomper [x] xs where
    chomper output@((a, b) : rest) element@(x, y)
        | x == b     = (a, y) : rest 
        | otherwise  = element : output
```

In other words you could also make this concrete to lists in Python and write instead:

```py
def foldl(fn, a, bs):
    """Fold a list from the left with `fn`. 

    This is a left fold, it takes an (A, B) -> A function and an A and a 
    list of Bs and produces an A."""
    z = a
    for b in bs:
        z = fn(z, b)
    return z

def chomper(output, element):
    (a, b) = output.pop()
    (x, y) = element
    if x == b:
        output.append((a, y))
    else:
        output.append((a, b))
        output.append(element)
    return output
```

Comment: foldl is implemented in python as `reduce`, in python 3.x they moved it to the module functools, so you can do `reduce(chomper,MyTuples,[])` and modify chomper so in case that output is a empty list, do `return [element] ` and it work perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short and neat way of doing it:

```
>>> l = [(0, 100), (100, 150), (150, 180), (180, 190), (400, 450), (450, 700)]
>>> l1, l2 = zip(*l)
>>> zip((i for i in l1 if not i in set(l2)), (i for i in l2 if i not in set(l1)))
[(0, 190), (400, 700)]
```

---

It's also easy with a little recursion, but cycles are going to cause infinite recursion:

```
def follow(d):
    # this finds the correct "ending" given a start point in the mapping
    follow_inner = lambda x: d[x] if d[x] not in d else follow_inner(d[x])
    for start in d:
        if start in d.values():
            # skip "linking" items
            continue
        yield start, follow_inner(start)
```

Use it like this:

```
lst = [(0,100),(100,150),(150,180),(180,190),(400,450),(450,700)]
filtered = list(follow(dict(lst)))
print filtered
# [(0, 190), (400, 700)]
```

There are obvious improvements this is just a POC. You can also use only generators (more fitting I suppose) - but I did this for fun :-)

Comment: The `set` is not crucial (only an improvement). It's really the same solution as the recursion and the one you did if you think of it... `zip` splits keys from values instead of the `dict`. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
MyTuples = [(0, 100), (100, 150), (150, 180), (180, 190), (400, 450), (450, 700)]



def con(l):
    it = iter(l)
    # pull first tuple
    tmp,  prev = next(it,((),()))
    for a, b in it:
        # compare prev b to current  a if they are != the sequence is broken
        if prev != a:
            yield tmp, prev
            tmp = a
        # update prev
        prev = b
    yield tmp, prev
print(list(con(MyTuples)))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 190), (400, 700)]
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but I guess it is because `[(180, 190), (450, 700)]` is not the correct output :(

Comment: No problem. Generators **is** the correct way of doing it IMO :-)

Comment: I actually found a nice way using `zip` (and sets for hash-comparison).